# How to parse unordered flags in arguments via getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt

```
int res = 0;
while ((res = getopt(argc, argv, "ivlcne")) != -1) {
    switch (res)
    {
    case 'i':
        pCurrentFlags->i = 1;
        break;

    case 'v':
        pCurrentFlags->v = 1;
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Using such a code, I encounter a problem. If I write *./a.out -i filename -v* in the terminal, the -v flag will not work.

Comment: To get that to work, you need GNU [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) and you need the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to be unset in your environment.

Comment: The traditional rule is that you can't mix options with non-option arguments. All the options come first, and `getopt` stops when it finds the first non-option argument (or the special `--` argument that ends options).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Commonly used practice to parse unordered flags is to parse all the arguments first and only after that handle them.

There is also a GNU implementation of the `getopt()` which supports that behavior as @Jonathan Leffler mentioned in the comments.

But from your copy, it is unclear what you are trying to do.
The `v` option in the code you provide needs an argument, but in the command line `./a.out -i filename -v` it is not taking it.

If you need `v` as a non-parameter option, the easiest way to make it work is to change `"ivlcne"` with `"i:v1:l:c:n:e"` and with this way `getopt()` will no longer wait for an argument for `v`.

Comment: The `getopt()` control string in the question does not require an argument for `-i`.  It does not use `i:` but just `i`.  The issue is how to interpret `-v` as an option even though it appears after an operand (_`filename`_ in the example invocation).  And to do that, you need a variant of `getopt()` that supports flags (like `-v`) after operands (like `filename`).  GNU `getopt()` is the best known such variant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 
Anyway if it is expecting for only `i`, you still need to write `i:v1` in `optstring` argument. Where `:` is just a delimiter between options and with `v1` you are telling getopt() that `v` option does not require an argument. This is valid sintax and getopt() can recognize it. :)

Comment: Yes, I did read it.  Did you?  There are no colons in the argument string for `getopt()` so none of the options expects a value.  The code for the `i` does not attempt to use `optarg`.  The question is about how to achieve the (sloppy) GNU-style argument processing where options are allowed to be interspered with non-option (operand) arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes and you can achieve that by using the delimiter `:` and append some number to the non-option character in the `opstring`. What I am trying to say is that the third argument of `getopt()` function is supporting delimiters, and you can pass the argument like `"i:v1:l:c:n:e:h1"` and it will be similar to `"ivlcneh"` except that you are telling `getopt()` that `v` and `h` are non-option arguments. This will work on any version of `getopt()` no matter its GNU or not. Did I say something misunderstood?

Comment: I don't think that's part of the POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html), nor are the numbers part of the GNU specification for [GNU `getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html).  And I've not seen a `getopt()` that supports your claimed syntax.  The `v1:` fragment will be interpreted as 'the letter `v` does not take an option argument and the digit `1` used as an option does require an option argument.

Comment: I also think you are willfully misinterpreting what the OP wrote in the question.  The filename is not the argument to the `-i` option — but you have tried to change the meaning of the command line to make it so that the `-i` option does take an argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not try to change anything. In the question there was the command line `./a.out -i filename -v`, and the question was why the `v` flag is not working. And the problem is that, by implementation in the question, the `v` flag requires an argument and in the command line it is not taking it. And the easiest way to make it work is to change `"ivlcne"` with `"i:v1:l:c:n:e"`. With this way `1` will be perceived as an argument for `v` and `getopt()` will no longer wait for an argument for `v`. If you do not believe try it.

Comment: As for the filename, I just wrote an example code of how to parse this argument properly.

Comment: The question title is "How to parse unordered flags in arguments via getopt in C".  The OP is asking how to parse such options — and the answer remains "Use GNU `getopt()` or an equivalent function that supports that behaviour".  Your non-solution changes the meaning of the `-i` option from being a flag into and option that takes an argument, which is not, IMNSHO, what the OP wants.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, You are absolutely right, I understood the question differently from the beginning, now I understand the order of the flags is the point of the question. I will update my post. Sorry for the pointless arguing and thanks for pointing me to what it was all about.